# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid

Tags: python, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, decision-tree

I've selected the features from my data set and then when I try to select those features from my data set, I get this error. Why is this happening?

```
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Banking Dataset.csv')
    LabelEncoder1 = LabelEncoder()
    independent_variables[:,1] = LabelEncoder1.fit_transform(independent_variables[:,1])
    LabelEncoder2 = LabelEncoder()
    independent_variables[:,2] = LabelEncoder2.fit_transform(independent_variables[:,2])


    onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
    independent_variables = onehotencoder.fit_transform(independent_variables).toarray()

    X_train, X_test, Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(independent_variables,target_values  ,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

    c = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=100)
    features =["CreditScore","Geography","Gender","Age","Tenure","Balance","NumOfProducts","HasCrCard","IsActiveMember","EstimatedSalary"]
    X = X_train(features)
```

Output:

FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  X_train=X_train[features]
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
X_train=X_train[features]
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Keep more attention when you edit your question. read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The issue you had in the question before the edit is still in your code. if you have further warnings or error provide it as edit or put it as a comment.so that it will be convenient to answer the question. otherwise, it may be downvoted or flagged. good luck brother

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
X=X_train[features]
```

instead of

```
X=X_train(features)
```

use `[]` when calling a numpy array

Comment: **Update ( future warning)**

The future warning says that your feature is a `list` not a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

the error code is saying that the specific line

`X=X_train(features)`

should have square braces [] around features intead of (). i.e.

`X=X_train[features]`

Comment: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  X_train=X_train[features]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tejus/PycharmProjects/Bankingproject/BankDecisionTree.py", line 60, in <module>
    X_train=X_train[features]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices